# Keeping variable value after Post using PHP_SELF

Tags: php, mysql

Im using this statement to retrieve my records:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE category = '$catvalue'");
```

The variable $catvalue is taken from an HTML select with different options using PHP_SELF in the action.

```
$catvalue = ($_POST['value']);
```

The problem is, I'm using paging on my page so every time I click one of my paging numbers I lose the value of `$catvalue` due to the paging ID (below) being stored in the url and my results then show nothing.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    ...
}
```

It works fine if I dont filter but I need both get and post to work. Any ideas or can anyone tell me what to learn up on?

Thanks!

Comment: Please stop using mysql functions which are deprecated and will not work in the future. Prefer to use PDO or mysqli instead. 
Not sure I understood what you want to but check at $_SESSION variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to remember `$_POST['value']` after refreshing page (eg. when you go to another page), store it in session.

```
if (isset($_POST['value'])) {
    $_SESSION['cat_value'] = $_POST['value'];
}
```

Don't forget to `session_start()` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: Thanks, I've had a read up on that now but still not sure what to add in my mysql in place of my variable? Do I add '$_SESSION['catvalue']' as I've tried that and that didnt work.

Comment: @bluesket: put into your query `$_SESSION['cat_value']` instead of `$catvalue`

Comment: Getting no results at all now using if (isset($_POST['value'])) {
$_SESSION['catvalue'] = $_POST['value'];
}

$sql=mysql_query("select * from myTable WHERE category = $_SESSION['catvalue'] LIMIT $start, $limit");

Comment: @bluesket: if it's non-numeric value, you forgot quotes around $_SESSION var in your query. If you put session_start() to beginning of your page, it will work.

Comment: Thank you so much!I changed  $_SESSION['catvalue'] to ’” . $_SESSION['catvalue'] . "' Works now.

Answer (score 2):

Two Solutions :

1) While adding pagination, you can pass the $catvalue as url query paremeter and fetch it with $_GET['catvalue'] or

2) Store the value of $catvalue in a session or cookie and read the value of it from session or cookie variable.

Answer (score 0):

First start the session using session_start(), Then use the below code.

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['value'])) {
    $_SESSION['catvalue'] = $_POST['value'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is my finished piece, thanks for the help.

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['value'])) {
echo $_SESSION['catvalue'] = $_POST['value'];
}
$sql=mysql_query("select * from myTable WHERE category='".$_SESSION['catvalue'] . "'");
```